# Jquery regexp dynamic expression

Tags: jquery, regex, dynamic

I have this `regexp` :

```
var regexp = /(2\d)(\W)/gi
```

Now I want to set it dynamically, meaning the value `2` can be changed like this :

```
var regexp = /(changablevalue\d)(\W)/gi
```

I tried :

```
var regexp = "/(" + changablevalue + "\d)(\W)/gi"
```

and

```
var changablevalue = 2
var regexp = /(changablevalue\d)(\W)/gi
```

but can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your regex to RegExp constructor.

```
var regex = new RegExp("("+changablevalue + "\\d)(\\W)", "gi")
```

Example:

```
> var changablevalue = 2
> var regex = new RegExp("("+changablevalue + "\\d)(\\W)", "gi")
undefined
> console.log(regex)
/(2\d)(\W)/gi
undefined
> regex.test('28.')
true
> regex.test('48.')
false
```

Comment: It still not working, do I need to install some additional classes?

Comment: Ah I see, the slashes

Comment: Since in the constructor you're passing the regex as a string, I believe that backslashes should be escaped. And so should the `changeablevalue` (if it will contain any "regex expressions", like `\w` for example.)